# AI shooting through walls

Tags: unity, collision-detection, ai, raycasting, unityscript

I made a AI shooting script for my new game but the problem is that the AI ignores the walls and shoots through walls. This is my ai script :

```
#pragma strict

public var rocketPrefab : Transform;
public var barrelEnd : Transform;
var canShoot : boolean = true;
var shootRate : float;
var gun : Transform;
var soundEffect : AudioClip;
var player : Transform;
var enemy : Transform;
var minShoot : float = 2;
var maxShoot : float = 4;

function Start ()
{

    e();
    canShoot = true;
}

function Update ()
{
    transform.LookAt(player);
    if(canShoot==true)
    {
        Shoot();
    }
}

function e()
{
    canShoot=false;
    yield WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(1, 2));
    canShoot=true;
}

function w()
{
    canShoot=false;
    yield WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(minShoot,maxShoot));
    canShoot=true;
}

function Shoot ()
{
        var rocketInstance : Transform;
        rocketInstance = Instantiate(rocketPrefab, barrelEnd.position, barrelEnd.rotation);
        w();
        audio.PlayOneShot(soundEffect);
}
```

Some help would be awsome! Thank you for your time.

Comment: You could check if player is visible to the AI enemy. But I am afraid there is no easy solution without tons of collisions detection code. You should at least read something about collision detections before asking for complete code for you situation.

Answer (score 1):

You should write a method that checks the visibility.

It follows the definition:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visibility_%28geometry%29

There are a lot of techniques to do that. Therefore, I reccomend you searching on the web which approach would fit best in your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use raycasting to check for visibility. Each raycast is expensive, so stagger the visibility checks for different enemies (they don't all have to see the player on the same frame)

Comment: How can you actualy make it so it runs in a different frame ? Should I be using lateUpdate ,fixedUpdate or so ? Or you got something else in mind.

Comment: I just mean use an 'if' statement in Update() before doing the visibility check. Probably use a static variable so that it's shared by all the enemies, and have each enemy increment it or something.